# Cannot identify the object in Selenium

Tags: object, selenium, webdriver, identification

I cannot identify the object of the icon showed in the attached screen shot.  I have shown the HTML code as well.

The ID's are getting changed dynamically.

Can anyone guide on how to identity this kind of objects in Selenium?

Comment: please add code and screenshot.

Comment: Where is the screenshot/HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is always changed, I recommend using CssSelector instead.
For instance,

```
<div id="running_number_12345" class="icon something">...</div>
```

You can use locator

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class*='icon something']"));
```

If your icon doesn't have any specific css pattern, I recommend adding something in class attribute. If not, you have to use complex CssSelector to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
  `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon something"));`

Comment: Please explain your answer.